# Anaconda overwrites curl

Tags: macos, curl, anaconda

I have homebrew and tried to do

```
brew install curl
```

to update it to the latest version.

However, `curl --version` was still returning an old version. When I did `which curl` it returned

```
/anaconda3/bin/curl
```

now I know if it has `usr/bin/curl` that i should update the PATH variable so that it updates the right `curl`. But I am unsure how to deal with it with `anaconda3` instead of `usr`.

I tried `conda remove curl` but conda is saying that `curl` is actually not at all installed here, which is curious. It says "The following packages are missing from the target environment: curl"

Answer (score 0):

New curl package is installed at /usr/bin, but your $PATH environment variable has /anaconda3/bin/ coming first. Hence system is able to find first occurrence of curl i.e. Older version.

The directory /anaconda3/bin occurs in $PATH before /usr/bin appears.

Your $SHELL picks the first curl it sees.

You have several choices:

1. Rearrange $PATH. However, if there are any other system binaries Anaconda wants to override, this will screw that up.
2. chmod -x /anaconda3/bin/curl;rehash will let you use /usr/bin/curl.
3. Add alias curl="/usr/bin/curl" to your ~/.bashrc. WIll only work for shells.